# Add Reference to Project at SVN Repository using Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, selenium

Consider the below scenario:

SVN Repository 01 -> Project 01
SVN Repository 02 -> Project 02
SVN Repository 03 -> Project 03

SVN Repository 04 -> Framework Project

Please let me know, how to reference the 'Framework Project' present in a 'SVN Repository' to other projects using the framework in Eclipse.

What I am trying to do here is that, any change I make to the 'Framework Project' should get reflected in all the linked projects without any additional compilation/process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can achieve this using maven. Install the Framework as a jar in the Maven repository and reference it in all the projects.